# UI elements not working in UIScrollView swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a scrollView and in the scrollview, I added a UIView. how ever, every property set on the uiview like color does not show. I set the background of the UIView to blue but does not show. I dont know if I am doing something wrong, below is my code

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let srv = UIScrollView()
        srv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return srv
    }()
    let contentView: UIView = {
        let cview = UIView()
        cview.backgroundColor = .blue
        cview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cview
    }()
```

in my viewDidLoad I added this

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

    contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollview` expects it's size from it's content , so set a width and height to `contentView` relative to main outer view

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier:2.0)
])
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. but I have a sumilar issue which I have asked as a question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415203/uiimageview-not-getting-rounded