# UIImageview not getting rounded

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to create a circular image and I have implemeted the right code but I do not know why it does not get rounded below is my code

```
lazy var profileImage: UIImageView = {
       let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        image.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        image.image = UIImage(named: "prof.jpg")
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        return image
    }()
```

and my constraints are

```
fileprivate func layout() {
        view.addSubview(profileImage)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        profileImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        profileImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        ])
}
```

layout() is then added to viewDidLoad

Comment: Where are you adding your image view to the view hierarchy? Where are you setting its constraints? You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Please don't forget to add the code image.layer.masksToBounds = true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re not giving your UIImageView a frame when it’s initialised so it uses `.zero` as a default. This means that when you access `image.frame.size.width` you are getting a value of 0.

What I would suggest is to move your `image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2` into the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` override on your `UIViewController` class.

You could also create a custom class that subclasses `UIImageView` and implements the same logic. The `override` for `UIImageView` would be `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score -1):

Image doesn't have a frame `*image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2*` inside the closure.

So set the corner radius after the profileImage is set with its constraints

```
profileImage.layoutIfNeeded()
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
```